# why i am getting this error "use of undeclared identifier 'allArtist' "

Tags: ios

I declared an array in `songViewController.h` as  `@property(retain,nonatomic) NSmutableArray allArtist`.
I used this array in another class `songdetailsViewController`. But it gives an error like: `use undeclared identifeir 'allArtist'`.

I have imported `songViewController.h` in `songdetailsViewController.h`

Comment: Show us your code. That will be helpful. How are you using allArtist? Are you creating instance of class `songViewController` in `songdetailsViewController`?

Comment: have you `@synthesize` your properties ?

Comment: i synthesized that property..i am just trying to print that array in other class but getting error like that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the property should be declared with a pointer:

```
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *allArtist;
```

To access it from the songdetailsViewController you have to set a second property there like:

```
@property(retain,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *allArtists;
```

and when you push the view set:

```
UIViewController *songdetailsViewController = [[songdetailsViewController alloc]
                                     initWithNibName:@"songdetailsViewController"
                                     bundle:nil];
 songdetailsViewController.allArtists = self.allArtist;

 [[self navigationController] pushViewController:songdetailsViewController animated:YES];
```

Finally you should consider moving your project to ARC.